# Rails. Doesn't work pluralization with KeyValue I18n Backend without subtrees

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I can't enable pluralization with Redis as I18n backend when subtrees is disabled.
I have:

config/initializers/i18n_backend.rb:

```
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.new(
    I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new(Redis.new, false),
    I18n.backend
)
```

seed.rb:

```
I18n.backend.store_translations(:ru,
  translation: {
    one: 'one %{count}',
    many: 'many %{count}'
  }
)
```

When I try execute:

```
I18n.t('translation', count: 1)
```

I get:

```
translation missing: "ru.translation"
```

I think the problem in algorithm of pluralization desribed in I18n::Backend::Base:

```
def pluralize(locale, entry, count)
      return entry unless entry.is_a?(Hash) && count

      key = :zero if count == 0 && entry.has_key?(:zero)
      key ||= count == 1 ? :one : :other
      raise InvalidPluralizationData.new(entry, count) unless entry.has_key?(key)
      entry[key]
end
```

Someone know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem. I just create own KeyValue Backend and a little bit monkey patch algorithm of interpolation:

config/initializers/i18n_backend.rb:

```
require 'i18n/backend/base'
require 'i18n/backend/chain'
require 'i18n/backend/key_value'
require 'i18n/backend/pluralization'

# Fixed pluralization for I18n::Backend::KeyValue without subtrees
class I18n::Backend::MyKeyValue < I18n::Backend::KeyValue
  include I18n::Backend::Pluralization

  def translate(locale, key, options = {})
    raise InvalidLocale.new(locale) unless locale
    count, default = options.values_at(:count, :default)
    values = options.except(*I18n::RESERVED_KEYS)
    key = "#{key}.#{pluralize_count_key(locale, count)}" if key && count

    entry = lookup(locale, key, options[:scope], options)
    entry = entry.nil? && default ? default(locale, key, default, options) : resolve(locale, key, entry, options)

    throw(:exception, I18n::MissingTranslation.new(locale, key, options)) if entry.nil?

    entry = interpolate(locale, entry, values) if values
    entry
  end

  protected

  def pluralize_count_key(locale, count)
    return unless count
    pluralizer = pluralizer(locale)
    count == 0 ? :zero : pluralizer.call(count) if pluralizer.respond_to?(:call)
  end
end

I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.new(
  I18n::Backend::MyKeyValue.new(Translation, false),
  I18n.backend
)
```

I don't think it's a nice solution, but it works.